# How to write ensembl rest api in PHP?

Tags: php, rest, google-api-php-client

Ensembl is a collection of genome database and annotation source for many eukaryotic genome. They have created REST API interface for user to access their data. http://rest.ensembl.org/. Also, provide detailed steps to write our own client ( perl, python etc.). I am learning PHP and hence would like to write PHP client, any suggestion will be helpful. Are there any libraries or class that I can use to effectively implement the client and access specific data and display back on html? Below is what I tired so far and work in progress.

```
$server = "http://grch37.rest.ensembl.org";
$ext = "/vep/human/hgvs/";
$hgvs_notation = "AGT:c.803T>C?content-type=application/json";
# added the  application header
$url = $server.$ext.$hgvs_notation;# updated based on comment
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: you probably want to concatenate as in `$url=$server.$ext.$hgvs_notation`;

Comment: I get a 415 http status code (invalid media type), the server end is probably anticipating some header indicating we accept json :) ... I use wrapped CURL for all my server/restful api calls.